# Iterate through mongoose object of array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, pug

I am trying to use the data from mongoose to populate data on a pug page using jquery.
Here is my code:

```
test.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$status',
                    count: {$sum: 1}
                }
            }
        ], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                res.render('graphs', {info: result});
            }
        });
```

This pulls the following data when I send the 'result' to the console:

```
[ 
  { _id: 'Pending', count: 10 },
  { _id: 'In Progress', count: 10 } 
]
```

In my pug template I am trying to loop through the results and pull the '_id' and 'count' for each object. I can do this on the node side with a for in loop but not on the pug side:

```
doctype html
html
head
title Main Page
script(type='text/javascript').
var results = "#{info}";
    $.each(results, function () {
        console.log(object);
    });
```

This is the error I receive and when I put 'info' to the console it give '[Object Object],[Object Object]'. Any help would be great.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ([object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `!{JSON.stringify(info)}` call to convert `info` to jade syntax for variables used in JavaScript:

```
doctype html
html
head
title Main Page
script(type='text/javascript').
  var results = !{JSON.stringify(info)}
  $.each(results, function () {
    console.log(object);
  });
```

Also, you should use proper indents, 2 or 4 spaces for each level.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I have been racking my brain for hours if not days trying to figure this out. Thanks.